# I am stuck attempting to set a udev hwdb to remap KEY_PRESENTATION to something compatible with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, udev, cinnamon

So I have an Acer Nitro laptop that I installed debian bookworm on running cinnamon DE. This laptop has a special "Nitro Sense" key by the numpad. When you push this key in windows, acer's bloat shits all over the machine, but on linux it sends keycode 425(KEY_PRESENTATION).

I want this key to open a terminal, so I attempted to make an xmodmap config, but it seems to be the case that only keycodes between 0-255 can work there. I know this because in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` this is defined:

```
// Key codes below cannot be used in X
<I433> = 433;           // #define KEY_PRESENTATION        425
```

So now im attempting to use udev to remap KEY_PRESENTATION to one of the 4 KEY_PROG keys and im not having much luck.

I am making a new file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/99-acer-nitro-nitrosense-key-remap.hwdb` with this inside:

```
evdev:input:b0011v0001p0001eAB41*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_f5=prog3
```

I built the input based on the output from my device's bustype, product, vendor, and version:

```
$ ls /sys/class/input/event0/device/id
bustype  product  vendor  version

$ cat /sys/class/input/event0/device/id/* 
0011 
0001 
0001 
ab41
```

I then run these commands, update initramfs, and restart the machine:

```
systemd-hwdb update 
(i have also tried running: udevadm hwdb --update)

udevadm trigger /dev/input/event0
```

but after restarting the machine, when I run `udevadm info /sys/class/input/event0` I see this line **KEYBOARD_KEY_f5=presentation** instead of **KEYBOARD_KEY_f5=prog3**

I am using **KEYBOARD_KEY_f5** because when I run evtest I get this output when I hit the key:

```
Event: time 1675476830.534080, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675476831.052993, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value f5
Event: time 1675476831.052993, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 425 (KEY_PRESENTATION), value 1
Event: time 1675476831.052993, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1675476831.166335, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value f5
Event: time 1675476831.166335, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 425 (KEY_PRESENTATION), value 0
Event: time 1675476831.166335, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

I am at a loss as to what to attempt next. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your keyboard probably counts as an AT keyboard, not a USB keyboard (run `sudo evemu-describe` to be sure). Just write a rule that applies to any AT keyboard:

```
evdev:atkbd:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_f5=prog3
```